# In unity urp 2d, is it possible to make the final render result only show a certain range of colors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, render

In unity urp 2d, is it possible to make the final render result only show a certain range of colors? For example, if there is lighting in the scene, there will be lots of colors in the render result, even though the original sprite might only have one color, but I would like to limit those colors to a certain range of colors I specified. Can post processing do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
You have various post processing effects to achieve this result in URP.

- Color Adjustments
- Color Curves
- Color Lookups
- Channel Mixer